# Random images getting color changes in listview

Tags: android, image, listview, picasso

My activity is a **listView**, which I am inflating using **MyAdapter** which extends **BaseAdapter**. My list view shows multiple images and I want to add a color filter effect,i.e. a change in color, to the images which have been already clicked.

At first all the images are shown as they are, but when user clicks on an image then its color changes, which kinda has a less brightened effect on the image,so user can know they have already seen this image before. I am achieving this by using `setColorFilter` methods.
And the image are changing after being clicked just fine.

My problem is, as I scroll down the listView several images which have not been clicked before are also showing this effect. Whereas i want this effect to show only on the clicked images.

**My code:-**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         public class ViewHolder{

                ImageView image;

            }

            @Override
            public View getView( final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
            {
                View vi = arg1;
                final ViewHolder holder;
                final int type = getItemViewType(arg0);

                if(arg1==null)
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    switch(type)
                    {
                    case 0:

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) itemlist.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, arg2,false);


                    holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                    holder.image.getLayoutParams().height=(int) (height/dpi); 

                    break;



                    }
                    vi.setTag(holder);
                }
                else{
                    holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
                }

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                       .load(data.get(arg0).get(3))
                       .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);

 holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.image.setColorFilter(0x70C6C6C6, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item"+arg0+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }});
}
            return vi;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maintain the state for the clicked images as below.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.check, null);
        holder.mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    final MyDataBean mDataBean = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataBean.getmString());
    if (mDataBean.isIschecked()) {
        holder.mImageView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    } else {
        holder.mImageView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
    holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDataBean.setIschecked(true);
            holder.mImageView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the type of your **data** array but maybe you can try to add some boolean into your **data** array like **isAlreadySeen** which is changed by your **onItemClickListener** method. So if there is nothing else in your list item except image, i would recommend you to use **onItemClickListener** outside of your adapter instead of **holder.image.setOnClickListener**. Then you can replace your

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        holder.image.setColorFilter(0x70C6C6C6, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
});
```

code with following

```
if(data.get(arg0).isAlreadySeen){
    holder.image.setColorFilter(0x70C6C6C6, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: This is exactly what I did, and its working. But I was looking for any other way without using separate variables to check everytime if the image is clicked or not.

Comment: then i will be following this thread. it would be nice to have a smarter solution. i hope someone will come with it!